# How do I submit an html form from button click when the android keyboard is open?

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, mobile-chrome

HTML form, on mobile Chrome / android

When the user clicks the button to submit at the bottom of the form, the behavior is it closes the keyboard (previously opened while entering a text field) and scrolls to center the original text field.  The user is then forced to scroll back to the bottom of the form to submit.

How do I submit the form on the initial button click?

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @jorel nothing yet, a bunch of similar related problems but nothing exactly the same.  I need to register that press as submit and not 'close keyboard'